# Apple Music api developer token

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am trying to get user token, what is user token, how to generate
    user token in ios app?

```
-(void) requestUserToken {
        if ([SKCloudServiceController authorizationStatus] == SKCloudServiceAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            SKCloudServiceController *serviceController = [[SKCloudServiceController alloc] init];

            if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
                [serviceController requestUserTokenForDeveloperToken:@"" completionHandler:^(NSString * _Nullable userToken, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"userToken_Error :%@", error);
                    }
                    else{
                        NSLog(@"userToken %@", userToken);
                    }
                }];
            } else {
                [serviceController requestPersonalizationTokenForClientToken:@"" withCompletionHandler:^(NSString * _Nullable personalizationToken, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    NSLog(@"personalizationToken %@", personalizationToken);
                }];
            }
        }
    }
```